# AWS Kinesis Data Analytics

Tags: analytics, amazon-kinesis

I am following this blog https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesisanalytics/latest/java/examples-python-sliding.html for creating the sample application. Once I start the application I get below error:

```json
{
    
    "applicationVersionId": 2,
    "message": "org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.handler.RestHandlerException: Could not execute application.\n\tat org.apache.flink.runtime.webmonitor.handlers.JarRunOverrideHandler.lambda$handleRequest$4(JarRunOverrideHandler.java:207)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniHandle(CompletableFuture.java:930)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniHandle.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:907)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:506)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1705)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)\nCaused by: java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramAbortException\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:314)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:319)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1702)\n\t... 6 more\nCaused by: org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramAbortException\n\tat org.apache.flink.client.python.PythonDriver.main(PythonDriver.java:111)\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)\n\tat org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.callMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:294)\n\tat org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.invokeInteractiveModeForExecution(PackagedProgram.java:201)\n\tat org.apache.flink.client.ClientUtils.executeProgram(ClientUtils.java:149)\n\tat org.apache.flink.client.deployment.application.DetachedApplicationRunner.tryExecuteJobs(DetachedApplicationRunner.java:78)\n\tat org.apache.flink.client.deployment.application.DetachedApplicationRunner.run(DetachedApplicationRunner.java:67)\n\tat org.apache.flink.runtime.webmonitor.handlers.JarRunOverrideHandler.lambda$handleRequest$3(JarRunOverrideHandler.java:203)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1700)\n\t... 6 more\n",
    "messageType": "ERROR",
    "messageSchemaVersion": "1",
    "errorCode": "CodeError.InvalidApplicationCode"
}
```

Anyone encountered such error, please help. Thanks in advance

Comment: hello, where you able to figure out what was wrong in this case? I am running into the same error. Any help would be useful.